# How to make parent menu active when the child menu was active in menu block using drupal 7?

Tags: menu, drupal-7

I have created menu and its child links like

```
About
  contact us
  portfolio
  our location
```

I have used menu block to display sub menu only when about in click and display sub menus in another layer.

Now my requirement is when i click on any sub menu in parent menu then the parent menu should be active. To achieve this task i searched a lot off and found menu position module for this purpose. I have configured and specify page path in Restricted to certain pages, but now it is now working. What i have mistake or any other solution for this problem. Please let me know the right solution.

[image]
[image]

```
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block_view', '1');
    print render($block['content']);
?>
```

I am adding this code below the topbar menu. but inside the menubar wrapper.

[image]

Comment: @Manish - it will be easier if you could upload the screen-shot of MenuBlock configuration screen.

Comment: Ok, Well, i am displaying menu block programtically in page.tpl.php.

Comment: @Manesh - thanks for uploading the screen-shot. Please post the code snippet from page.tpl.php which you are using to display menu block. I am trying to assist you to give all required information so community members can answer your question.

Comment: Ok. I am updating my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no requirement to use any module for this situation. What i have done to achieve it. I just modified template.php of zurb foundation theme. i have [copied the code(foreach loop code) from here](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/zurb_foundation--add_active_trail_to_menus--issue-2103997.patch) and added to the template.php file as mentioned in the page and added the css like below:

```
#main-menu li.active-trail  a,
#main-menu li a.active, #main-menu li a:hover {
  background:#fec325;
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

and that's it. i have achieve what i want. I hope anybody who is looking same kind of problem can find this solution useful for this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding clear then you will need this menu - **`Menu Position`** https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position

This module allows for the creation of rules that will dynamically add the current page into the menu system at the requested spots.

If you dont want to use this module then you will need to append `menu-id` in the menu link's `li` and then through jquery / js will need to add certain classes to parent menu items.

Comment: Block is displaying correctly, but the issue is when i select any child in menu block then the prent menu must be active. I have search a lot of thing aand found that context and menu position can do. but in my case it is not working.

Comment: I have tried this module but, its not working for path which is specified except <front>.

Comment: I have used menu position and putting screen shot of the configuration. Please see and let me why about link is not active.